# Having trouble booting ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, grub2, partitioning

https://i.stack.imgur.com/itwJ3.jpg

I get this error after I try to boot ubuntu from USB. I have an 
8 gig PNY flash drive and I have formatted it with Rufus and followed many different guides to try and get this to work. I end up getting this error every time does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> nouveau init failed

The nouveau (open source nVidia driver) is failing to initialize. You can try adding "nomodeset" as parameter to the kernel and see if that works, it should.

See screenshot below and when starting Ubuntu Live, make sure you select the "Try Ubuntu without installing option".

WARNING: If you choose to install the OS, chances are you will have the same issue and your freshly installed Ubuntu may not start and you will need to do a similar mod.

[image]